# Problems with ToUnicode function and accents

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, keyboard

Searching this site I saw that someone else was having the same problem using the ToUnicode function and result in double accents. Example of my code removing unimportant parts:

In my cpp file ( the window has been with the creation function CreateWindowsEx):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:{
        //keyboard
        rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY |RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
        rid[0].usUsagePage = 1;                         
        rid[0].usUsage = 6;
        rid[0].hwndTarget = hWnd;

        //mouse
        rid[1].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY |RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
        rid[1].usUsagePage = 1;
        rid[1].usUsage = 2;
        rid[1].hwndTarget = hWnd;
        RegisterRawInputDevices(rid,2,sizeof(rid[0]));
                   }
    case WM_INPUT:
        KeyProcess(message,lParam); 
        break;
```

In my dll file:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyProcess(UINT msg, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPBYTE lpb = nullptr;
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INPUT:
        if(GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam,RID_INPUT,NULL,&dwSize,sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER))==-1){
            break;
        }
        lpb = (LPBYTE)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, dwSize);
        if(lpb==NULL){
            break;
        } 
        if(GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam,RID_INPUT,lpb,&dwSize,sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER))!=dwSize){
            GlobalFree(lpb);  
            break;
        }

        PRAWINPUT raw=(PRAWINPUT)lpb;

        if(raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
        {
            UINT Event;
            raw->data.keyboard.MakeCode; 
            raw->data.keyboard.Flags;
            raw->data.keyboard.Reserved;
            raw->data.keyboard.ExtraInformation; 
            raw->data.keyboard.Message;
            raw->data.keyboard.VKey;

            Event = raw->data.keyboard.Message;     

            if(Event == WM_KEYDOWN)
            {                   
                int ta = ToUnicode(raw->data.keyboard.VKey,raw->data.keyboard.MakeCode,
                    bChar,&wChar,1,0);
                ta = ToUnicode(raw->data.keyboard.VKey,raw->data.keyboard.MakeCode,
                    bChar,&wChar,1,0);
```

Where bChar is BYTE bChar[256] and wChar is WCHAR wChar;

According to what I read indicated the solution was to call twice ToUnicode function so that when keying, e.g shift over the character "6" (where the accent '¨' german umlaut) and then the character 'e' I would as a result the character 'ë'.
If I call the function only once generated is double german umlaut accent, but calling the function twice the accent is placed on the string, but does not appear in notepad, as if the key was defective. When the executed program stop the behavior of the key back to normal. What am I doing wrong? I've tested with:

```
if (ta == -1) break;
```

With or without test is always the same error. With the mouse everything works as expected, but the keyboard is that nothing works tried.

Answer (score -1):

Don't mess with WM_INPUT for text, it is too low-level.
You will break IMEs and other text input.